# Add Record to ICollection Based on Generic Argument

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

Is there a way to access an `ICollection` on a record based on a generic type `(T)` as the selector?

I have an class called `Job` that has numerous `ICollection` of answers.

```
public class Job
{
    public ICollection<OperationAnswer> OperationAnswers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ElectricalAnswer> ElectricalAnswers { get; set; }  
}
```

I want to be able to add items to these answer `ICollections` based on the generic type argument `(T)` that I have passed to the method.

Currently I have to do an `if` statement to check the generic type `(T)` and then manually access the correct answer collection to add a new record. Here is an example.

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(ElectricalAnswer))
{
    job.ElectricalAnswers.Add(new ElectricalAnswer
    {

    });
}
else if (typeof(T) == typeof(OperationAnswer))
{
    job.OperationAnswers.Add(new OperationAnswer
    {

    });
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this where the `AddToAnswerCollection` extension method would know which answer collection to use?

```
jobStageZone.AddToAnswerCollection<T>(new T
{
    //properties
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Or... just use overload resolution

```
public void AddAnswer(OperationAnswer answer)
  => OperationAnswers.Add(answer);

public void AddAnswer(ElectricalAnswer answer)
  => ElectricalAnswers.Add(answer);
```

Or Implement an interface or bass class and store them in the same list

Comment: Im confused as to how each method has a parameter that adds itself to itself? OperationAnswers answer => OperationAnswers.Add(answer)

Comment: @BadDub sorry typo

Comment: I also cant store them as one list as they have different properties but inherit from the same base interface.

Comment: @BadDub if they share any bass class or interface, you surely can store them in the one list. `public ICollection<ISomethingShared> Answers { get; set; }` However the down side, is you will always have to cast, or use `TypeOf<T>` to access them